# Cannot disable CUDA build and the process stops

Tags: cmake, arrayfire

Trying to build ArrayFire examples, everything goes well until I get to the CUDA ones. They are supposed to be skipped, since I have an AMD processor/GPU. However, during the build process, the CUDA section is built anyway, failing for obvious reasons, interrupting the rest of the process.

I could manually change the `CMakeLists.txt` files. However, is there a higher level way to let the build system (cmake) know that I do not have a CUDA compatible GPU?

It looks like the `ArrayFire_CUDA_FOUND` and `CUDA_FOUND` macros are erroneously defined on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArrayFire CMake build provides a flag to disable the CUDA backend. Simply set `AF_BUILD_CUDA` to `NO` via `-DAF_BUILD_CUDA=NO` at the command line to disable CUDA.

Comment: Does that macro have to be set when building ArrayFire, or when building an application that uses ArrayFire? In my case I downloaded the prebuilt Linux version, and may have to build it myself...

Comment: When building ArrayFire from sources.